# how to convert DBMS_METADATA Oracle to Postgres?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, dbms-metadata

How to convert DBMS_METADATA Procedures and Functions for Submitting XML Data  in oracle to postgresql

For example :

```
SET serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
  v_handle NUMBER;
  v_transform_handle NUMBER;
  v_ddls  sys.ku$_ddls;
  v_ddl   sys.ku$_ddl;
BEGIN
  v_handle := DBMS_METADATA.OPEN ('OBJECT_GRANT');
  v_transform_handle := DBMS_METADATA.ADD_TRANSFORM(v_handle, 'DDL');
  DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(v_transform_handle,'PRETTY', TRUE);
  DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(v_transform_handle,'SQLTERMINATOR',TRUE);
  DBMS_METADATA.SET_FILTER(v_handle, 'BASE_OBJECT_NAME', 'TABLE_NAME' );
  DBMS_METADATA.SET_FILTER(v_handle, 'BASE_OBJECT_SCHEMA', 'OWNER_NAME' );
  DBMS_METADATA.SET_COUNT (v_handle, 10); -- 10 object by call to fetch
  v_ddls := DBMS_METADATA.FETCH_DDL(v_handle);
  WHILE (v_ddls IS NOT NULL) 
   LOOP
    FOR indx IN 1 .. v_ddls.COUNT  
      LOOP
       v_ddl := v_ddls(indx);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Output: ' || v_ddl.ddlText);
    END LOOP;
    v_ddls := DBMS_METADATA.FETCH_DDL(v_handle);
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_METADATA.CLOSE (v_handle);
END;
/
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no equivalent in Postgres.

Comment: Is there no other alternative? Create other tables that do the same?